# How to change the StaticResource of a style with Visual States in a Windows 8.1 App

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have a Windows 8.1 Application with a TextBlock.
I want to control the style of the TextBlock based on the state in which the app is in.
1. Snapped
2. Fullscreen.

The styles are loaded through StaticResources.

Here is the style, that I want to load in Snapped View

```
<Style x:Key="SnappedTextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="Blue" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize"
            Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight"
            Value="ExtraBlack" />
</Style>
```

Here is the style, that I want to load in Fullscreen

```
<Style x:Key="FullscreenTextBlockStyle"
       TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="Red" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize"
            Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight"
            Value="Black" />
</Style>
```

The way I assign the initial Style to the TextBlock is

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource FullscreenTextBlockStyle}" />
```

I don't want to modify the individual properties directly on the TextBlock elements.

One workaround I am aware of, is to use a boolean variable IsSnapped and load different styles using a converter.

```
<TextBlock Style={Binding IsSnapped, Converter={StaticResource SnappedToStyleConverter}} />
```

However, I don't like the above approach. Because I feel it is a good idea to put all my code related to states in Visual states than handle it from different places.

I would be very glad if someone can point me in the right direction.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So usually what I actually do is create two textblocks, then hide the ones which are not being shown at the time. You can also create two separate design surfaces (such as a snapped grid content and non-snapped grid content). You could try setting the Style with an ObjectKeyFrameAnimation, but you may need to do some kind of Invalidation on it for it to redraw. If the binding works then this may not be necessary. You may also try creating a custom LayoutAwareTextBlock which takes two styles and switches between them automatically.

Comment: Thanks, for now I have created two Textblocks and controlling it's visibility. I am curious about LayoutAwareTextBlock that you mentioned above, if you have more info, please do provide the same as an answer to this question. I will also try giving it a shot.

Comment: For LayoutAwareTextBlock you would have to create a custom class which extends from TextBlock. This extension would have a class-wide event listener to the window size changed. It would have different dependency properties for each state. You could also create a list of page width definitions if you wanted to and use a list of these as the dependency property. Then, when the window size change event triggers, it determines if there is a new visual state to go to and goes to that state.